# Conversion of 2 letter combination into 3 digit number (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert the "nth day in the year" into a two-letter combination, and vice versa, in excel.

The way it goes is, AA = 001 (January 1), AB = 002 (January 2), MT = 332 (November 28), up to the 365th (or 366th) day, and so on.

Anyone have any ideas how I can do this? Any help is appreciated!

Edit: VLookup would be easy but I'm trying to hard code it into the sheet.

**Edit 2**: Rephrasing for clarity.

Input: 2 letter character and a year that will be sourced from another cell

Output: Relevant date for both leap year and non-leap year

The alternate Input and Output I kindly ask for is the opposite of the above, which is to enter the date and output the 2 letter code.

The typical string source for the operation will look something like: **0MT**

"0" corresponds to the year "2020" and "MT", as opposed to what I first wrote, actually corresponds to November 27 since 2020 is a leap year.

Comment: Can you please state your input and output clearly? I think all things can be taken care of, leap year non-year! But please state what is your input and what is desired output?

Comment: Isn't 0MT a very short span for a code type. That will only give you nine years before this loops around and causes problems.

Comment: @Andreas 0MT is actually part of a larger code e.g. 0MTRWMY. Disregard "R" and "W" ."MT" and "MY" are in MMDD format. But I understand that "0" can either be interpreted as 2020 or 2030. I guess a recode before 2030 comes would be acceptable.

Comment: See my edited answer, if I am getting it correct now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Excel's `ADDRESS` and `COLUMN` functions.

***Number to 2 letter code:***

```
B2: =LEFT(ADDRESS(1,26+A2,4),2)
```

***2 letter code to Number:***

```
C2: =COLUMN(INDIRECT(B2&1))-26
```

Note that converting to an actual date will require taking the year into account due to leap year variation.

[image]

### EDIT

Seems you have changed your question, but variations on the above formulas will answer your new question:

***Date from three character code:***
*Note that the decade must be hard coded, since you only provide a single digit for the year*

```
B2: =DATE(202&LEFT(A2),1,COLUMN(INDIRECT(RIGHT(A2,2)&1))-26)
```

***Three character code from date:***

```
B6: =MOD(YEAR(A6),10) &LEFT(ADDRESS(1,A6-DATE(YEAR(A6)-1,12,31)+26,4),2)
```

[image]

Comment: How would the code look like if the year is taken into account?

Comment: @LouisMichaelSurabia The code I posted would not change at all.  It's just converting a number to a two letter code, and reverse, which is what you asked for.

Comment: @LouisMichaelSurabia See the update taking into account your Edit for different inputs and outputs.

Comment: Tried this for both leap year and non-leap year, and it worked. Will be using this one. Thank you!

Comment: Hi  Ron. Would just like to ask how COLUMN(INDIRECT(RIGHT(A2,2)&1))-26 works in returning the value "27"?

Comment: Kind of found it out on my own, but will comment here to see if I got it right.

Indirect Function returns "MT1". Column function returns the numerical value of Column MT which is 332, which is then interpreted by the Date function.

Still don't know why month is inputted as "1", and what the "&1" and "-26" parts are for.

Comment: @Louis `COLUMN(MT)` is not valid. The argument must be a valid address. Hence the `&1` so that the function reduces to `COLUMN(MT1)`  But, to get the two character code, starting with `AA`, we added 26 to the original day count, so now we have to subtract that value. (Column (mt1) ---> 358).  And since we are adding days starting with January, the month argument has to be `1`.

Comment: I understand the code well now. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

I quick fix would be to convert the text to date using:

=TEXT(A1,"dd mmmm")

or =TEXT(A1,"mmmm dd")

or =TEXT(A1,"mmmm d")

[image]

Comment: Was about to edit my question to convert the 3 digit numbers into actual dates. You answered it before I could ask!!! Thank you!!

Comment: This formula is based on year 1900. It will not work correctly when it's leapyear

Answer (score 1):

You can use relatively simple formulas here:

- convert numbers to letters: `=CHAR(INT((A2-1)/26)+CODE("A"))&CHAR(MOD(A2-1,26)+CODE("A"))`
- convert letters to numbers: `=TEXT((CODE(LEFT(B2))-CODE("A"))*26+CODE(RIGHT(B2))-CODE("A")+1,"000")`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This eliminates my need to use vlookup. 

Follow up question, how will the formulas account for leap years (or at the very least, be adjusted accordingly), since days after February 29 will be assigned a different 2 letter combination?

Comment: @LouisMichaelSurabia just try it. Just add 366 and see what happens. I'm quite sure it will work.

Comment: Actually. This is also based on year 1900.

Comment: @Andreas I think the above given code only works for non-leap years. i.e. for 2021, CH will translate to march 1, whereas CH will translate to Feb. 29 in any leap year. I figure all the other letter combination - date correspondences will be affected by leap years.

Comment: @LouisMichaelSurabia Update your question with how this will be used

Comment: @LouisMichaelSurabia What is expected? Is CG supposed to be 28/2 and CI 29/2 (if applicable), then 1/3 be CH? Is that what you want?

Comment: @Andreas I was thinking more of the code adjusting if the year (to also be input in the code) falls on a leap year.

In essence, the the year is 2020, inputting CH will output Feb. 29, then all other letter designations will adjust accordingly.

Comment: @LouisMichaelSurabia AGAIN... Edit your post with how this will be used. This is getting frustrating. We can help you but not if you keep resisting like this. What is the input? Is it todays date? In that case that would have been an essential thing to include. What do you want the output to be in case of leap year? In case of non leap year?

Comment: My apologies @Andreas. This is my first time posting here on stackoverflow and am not familiar with convention. Also not in an IT/programming related college program. Will edit the post now accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**  Based on you edits, what I can understand is you have two inputs (charachters and year) and you want date therefrom:  Use this formula (see screenshot below for correct understanding)

```
=TEXT(((CODE(LEFT($A3,1))-65)*26)+(CODE(RIGHT($A3,1))-64)+DATE(B$2,1,1)-1, "dd mmmm")
```

For **vice versa** part i.e. you want to convert day number of any year to code, use this formula

```
=CHAR(QUOTIENT(F3,26)+65)&CHAR(MOD(F3,26)+64)
```

Here year is redundant.  See this screenshot

[image]

**OLD answer:** OR you could directly convert the two albhabet code to month, by using

```
=TEXT(((CODE(LEFT(A1,1))-65)*26)+(CODE(RIGHT(A1,1))-64),"dd mmmm")
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know it, but this is actually what I needed. 

How would it be coded in such a way that when I input the date, the two letter combination comes out? and how would the formula account for leap years?

Comment: This formula is based on year 1900. It will not work correctly when it's leapyear

Comment: see edited answer for this year consideration.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the expected output where it skips CH in years with no leap year then the following will be what you need.

[image]

In B1 I have this formula to get the number from a date:

```
=IF(MOD(YEAR(A1),4)<>0,IF((A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)+1)>59,A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)+2,A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)+1),A1-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)+1)
```

So if it's a non leap year it skips day 60.

Then column D and E is the formula from Máté Juhász answer, but I'm sure the other answers conversion formulas work just as good.
The thing is to make it react to the current year and leap-years which is what I included in the B-column.